# Hadoop HA Namenode goes down with the Error: flush failed for required journal

Tags: hadoop, namenode

```
Namenode goes down with below error:
using hadoop version : 2.0.0
```

**ERROR**

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Starting log segment at XXXXXX
FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Error: flush failed for required journal (JournalAndStream(mgr=FileJournalManager(root=/XXXXXXXX/HA/edits), stream=EditLogFileOutputStream(/XXXXXXXXXXXX/HA/edits/current/edits_inprogress_00000000000XXXXXXX)))
java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.force0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.force(FileDispatcherImpl.java:75)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.force(FileChannelImpl.java:363)
    ......
   .org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet$JournalSetOutputStream.flush(JournalSet.java:456)
    at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
    /************************************************************
     SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at CDCTPHADOOPAP1/IP_ADDRESS
     ************************************************************/
```

Can someone help me in understanding the exact cause for this issue and how to resolve this.

Comment: The journal node was not able to copy the edit-logs from the namenode, so the journal nodes decided to kill the namenode